# How Do I Make A Bar In C# Which Changes According To A Variable?

Tags: c#, charts

So I made this button, that on click does this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(4000, top);
}
```

but instead of adding a bar, it adds lines. :(

**PS** : I am not good at this

Comment: You need to set the [type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.seriescharttype?view=netframework-4.8) of chart you want. Column is default but to get bars use : `this.chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
` - Note that you can change the charttype at any time. Also note that all Bar-types have their x- and y-axes switched!! - Finally note that while various series in the same chart can have different types not all type are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the chart control via toolbox or dynamically ?
If you used the toolbox and the control showed bars in the designer, the same should happen here.
My best guess would be you set the *Series1.ChartType* to a line chart.
What happens if you change your code to

```
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(4000, top);
```

Comment: Thanks! I made this with toolbox